# Laravel Routes and Vue Route Conflicts

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to create a SPA with laravel and vue. Also installed Voyager for admin purposed. Voyager is http://localhost:8000/admin .. which used laravel web route.

Can't access it now i'm using Vue Router for my routes:
Example for my Home Route (vue) http://localhost:8000/home

**app.js**

```
...
import VueRouter from  'vue-router';

import App from './components/App.vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
    ],
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    router,
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Vue Router Demo App</h1>

        <p>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">Home</router-link> |
        </p>

        <div class="container">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <p>This is the homepage</p>
</template>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <app></app>
@endsection
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318370/how-to-use-laravel-authentication-and-vue-router-together/55318849#55318849

Answer (score 5):

ok i solved it!!

exchanging the order of routes declaration in we.

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});

Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```