# How to handle Laravel routing using AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-routing

I am completely new to Laravel + AngularJs. What I want to do is handle my web.php routes using AngularJs. Is it possible? If it how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SPA and your app is using HTML5 history mode, this should be similar to how people often combine Laravel and VueJS routing.

You'd usually have all of your non-Angular routes at the top of `routes/web.php` and then a "catch-all" route for your SPA. This "catch-all" route is basically a route that doesn't care what the route looks like; it will just send it on to the AngularJS app.

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55318849/3486675) or [this article](https://medium.com/@piethein/how-to-combine-vuejs-router-with-laravel-1226acd73ab0) your `routes/web.php` might look something like:

```
Route::resource('Videos', 'VideoController')->middleware('auth','isAdmin');
Route::resource('Categories', 'CategoriesController')->middleware('auth');
...
Route::get('/{angularjs_capture?}', function () {
 return view('angularjs.index');
})->where('angularjs_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

And then you'd have a view at `/resources/views/angularjs/index.blade.php` that contains the base HTML for your SPA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Delena Malan. What I want in my application is, if user clicks on a link it should not reload the page but render the page in a ng-view. Can I do this and how?

Comment: Yes, have a look at [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples). It should do what you're looking for :)